# How to use the Ruby I18n gem to translate in an each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, rails-i18n

I'm creating a site in English and Spanish using the I18n Ruby gem in a Ruby on Rails application.

```
<% @client.client_applications.each do |application| %>
  <%= link_to "#{application.class.to_s}", "/#{application.class.to_s.downcase}s/#{application.id}", :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

The applications are foreclosures, rentals, and homebuying. I know how to translate a regular link_to, but I can't figure out how to translate it when it's looping through the three applications.